# Macro to copy formatted cells and paste into new sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to generate new sheets based on a summary list. In addition to the summary list sheet I have another sheet with formatted cells that I want copied into the new sheets that are automatically being created from the summary list. I tried using the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Sub createsheets()

Dim data_export As Worksheet
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim MasterForm As Worksheet


Dim r As Integer

r = 2

Do While Sheets("data_export").Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""

Set newSheet = Sheets.Add

newSheet.Name = Sheets("data_export").Cells(r, 1).Value

Sheets("MasterForm").Range("A1:E13").Copy

Sheets("newSheet.Name").Range("A1:E13").Paste

r = r + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. `Sheets("newSheet.Name").Range("A1:E13").Paste` is wrong though. When you put quotes around `newSheet.Name` VBA only sees the string `"newSheet.Name"` and you probably don't have a tab with the name `"newSheet.Name"` because that would be wierd.

You already have a sheet object stored in variable `newSheet` no need to use the `Sheets` object again. Just do:

```
newSheet.Range("A1:E13").Paste
```

Furthermore, you can copy/paste without having to involve the systems clipboard. Just do:

```
newSheet.Range("A1:E13").value = Sheets("MasterForm").Range("A1:E13").value
```